# How to print the sum of the series of choice b

Tags: java, switch-statement, series

I am new to this site I may have asked the question in the wrong manner, please forgive

I have completed the choice a but I can't get the desired result for the sum of choice b
I can print the series but can't print the sum  2 – 5 + 10 – 17 + 26 – 37 + …. Up to n terms

```
import java.util.*;
class menu
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String choice="";
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your choice 'a' or 'b'");
        choice=sc.nextLine();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case "a":
            int i,j;
            for ( i=1; i <=5; i++)
            {
                for (j=5; j >=i; j--)
                {
                    if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                        System.out.print("1 ");
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.print("0 ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            break;
            case "b":
            System.out.println("Enter 'n' th term"); 
            int sum=0,f,s,into,n;
            n=sc.nextInt();
            for(f=1;f<=n;f++)
            {
                s=(f*f+1);
                sum+=s;
                
                
            }
            System.out.print(sum);
            break;
            default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Choice");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can print the series, what's stopping you from printing the sum of the series?

Comment: i can't do the +  -   alternate sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a `sgn` variable that flips between 1 and -1.
Multiply each term by `sgn` before adding it to the sum, then flip `sgn` to get ready for the next term:

```
int sgn = 1; 
for(f=1;f<=n;f++)
{
    s=sgn*(f*f+1);
    sum+=s;
    sgn *= -1;
}
```